# How to create a subsignal / subvariable from an entity variable in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am currently implementing a MIPS processor in VHDL. The system component (which glues together the ALU, register file, control unit, etc.) has the follow entity description:

```
entity system is
    port (
                 reset : in std_logic;
                 sys_clk : in std_logic;
                 instruction : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
                 sys_mem_dump : in std_logic := '0'
         );
end system;
```

In the architecture section of this system, I am trying to create "subvariables" of the instruction variable, corresponding to the opcode and registers in use.

```
architecture Behavioral of system is
        instruction_opcode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := instruction(15 downto 12);
        instruction_rd : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := instruction(11 downto 8); -- destination register
        instruction_rs : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := instruction(7 downto 4); -- source register
        instruction_rt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := instruction(3 downto 0); -- target register
        -- a bunch of signals
begin 
    -- a bunch of port maps
end Behavioral
```

I've tried `signal`, `variable`, `shared_variable`, and `constant`, but these result in the register file's addresses not being initialized when I port map one of these variables to it.  I've also tried putting these variables in the system entity port, but that also doesn't work.  I don't want to split the `instruction` variable in the system entity port into those four variables either.

Comment: Please read your professors course material or a book or any other resource about VHDL, because fundamental knowledge is missing.

Comment: @Paebbels Is it simply not possible to do this in VHDL?  I have looked at the synario manual and some other websites, and none of the data object types match this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agree with paebles: you seem to lack basic VHDL knowledge and should look for this in your book.

You should at least know this method:

```
architecture Behavioral of system is
    signal instruction_opcode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    instruction_opcode <= instruction(15 downto 12);
end architecture;
```

But you can in fact use aliases:

```
architecture Behavioral of system is
    alias instruction_opcode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) is instruction(15 downto 12);
begin
end architecture;
```

Comment: There is practically no VHDL in my book, and we were expected to learn VHDL last semester, which did not happen in the slightest.  Thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

A common thread reflecting your comment

> @Paebbels Is it simply not possible to do this in VHDL? I have looked at the synario manual and some other websites, and none of the data object types match this use case.

is that the references you have used are inadequate.

In addition to intermediary signals and object aliases described in JH Bonarius' answer there is a method using index ranges declared as subtypes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity field is
    port (
        fourbitfield:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of field is 
begin
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity system is
    port (
        reset:          in  std_logic;
        sys_clk:        in  std_logic;
        instruction:    in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        sys_mem_dump:   in  std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity system;

architecture foo of system is
    subtype opcode is integer range 15 downto 12;
    subtype rd is integer range 11 downto 8;
    subtype rs is integer range 7 downto 4;
    subtype rt is integer range 3 downto 0;
begin
U1: 
    entity work.field port map (instruction(opcode));

U2: 
    entity work.field port map (instruction(rd));

U3: 
    entity work.field port map (instruction(rs));

U4: 
    entity work.field port map (instruction(rt));
end architecture;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and simulates (Not actually doing anything while proving a lack of bounds errors).

An entity is an independent design unit and naturally allows abstraction (port names are associated with actual signals in a port map during elaboration of a component instantiation). All other forms of names or using intermediary objects are forms of abstraction intended for readability and are dictated by style.

In the above `instruction(opcode)` and it's like are slice names (IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.5 Slice names) providing a discrete range in the form of a integer subtype. You could likewise use slice names with discrete ranges (e.g. 15 downto 12) as actuals in association lists directly without declaring subtypes:

```
U1:
    entity work.field port map (fourbitfield => instruction(15 downto 12));
```

Using named association between formal port and actual signals shown here can preclude the need for further abstraction. Dictating abstraction impinges on style not required by the VHDL standard.

Your idea of sub signals or variables aligns with slice names in VHDL as easily as the use of intermediary signals. Aliases are simply other names for named entities (including object slices).

Which additional abstraction method if any you use might depend on the sophistication level of anticipated readers.

If someone were to search the [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag on Stackoverflow thoroughly you'd find examples of all three of these methods. A wile reader could edit your question to align with VHDL syntax and submit it as a duplicate.

Comment: Good suggestion. This looks nice. I'm now suddenly considering that an alternative would be to use `record`s a la `instruction.opcode`. But you would need some conversion function slv->record. And of course `opcode` should then be an ennumerated type.... etc.